# Selection of the three largest values in the numpy table

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, text-classification

I am doing a text classification, I want to use the class probability for the three classes that have the highest probabilities.I need your help. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
probability = get_predict_proba(X)
print(probability)
```

[[0.15682828 0.11664342 0.11088368 0.12925814 0.09544043 0.10655934
0.14538805 0.13899866]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
np.argsort(probability)[-3:] # 3 'best' classes
probability[np.argsort(probability)[-3:]] # 3 'best' probabilities
```

(`np.argsort` gives you the sorted indices.)

Comment: Hi Julien, np.argsort(probability)[-3:] # 3 'best' classes, it is worked but given all classes. but i tried this: np.argsort(probability)[-3:] = P, P[:, -3:] To get the 3 best classes.